# Conservation of linear momentum not giving right result for colliosion of lighter body with heavier body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

In collision momentum always remains conserved that is total initial momentum is equal to total final momentum. Now suppose first object is ball and the second object is very very heavy like a floor. So the velocity of floor remains zero before the collision and after the collision. Now if I apply the concept of conservation of momentum considering the masses of objects as M1 and M2 and their initial velocity is u1 and u2 and final velocity is V1 and V2 respectively as follows:

m1u1 + m2u2 = m1v1 + m2v2

Now as the second object being very heavy like floor; it's velocity remains 0 throughout so m2u2 and m2v2 becomes zero, which means

m1u1 = m1v1 => u1 =v1

But how can u1 be equal to v1 , because a ball when it hits the ground it will bounce back. So both velcoties must be in opposite direction (v1 = -u1). but according to above equation velocities are equal and in same direction.
How is this possible?

Comment: Please use MathJax for writing formulas.

Comment: The velocity of the floor being close to zero does not mean that its momentum is zero, since its mass is very large.